# Complex ajax request to spring post method

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot

I need to pass complex data structure to post method. I don't know how to form it in the js method. I need to pass in the post method `Map<String, List<String>>`. How to get this sturcture in js. And how to pass it in post method?

Comment: I'd guess in JS / JSON it'd be an object where each key contains an array, something like `{ "a": ["1", "2", "3"], "b": ["4", "5", "6"] }`  . P.S. You can easily google how to send JSON in the body of an AJAX POST request.

Answer (score 3):

As [@ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) suggests, it looks like the form of data you need in JSON would be something like this:

```
{ "a": ["1", "2", "3"], "b": ["4", "5", "6"] }
```

You can use `fetch` to send ajax requests. If you'd prefer not to use fetch then there are many alternatives but it isn't really worth listing them here.

```
fetch('http://www.yourendpoint.com/whatever-route', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({a: ["1", "2", "3"], b: ["4", "5", "6"] }),
})
```